# How to create new text file on the fly if one file overflow in java

Tags: java, json, filewriter

I am writing json data into one file. It works fine for small data but for large data it is writing some amount of data and remaining data gets skipped. So Please guide me how to create new file if one gets fulled in java? 
Currently i am using below code to write json object into a file.

Below is the sample which is quite similar to my working code.

```
 String json=null;
                for(int counter=0;counter<2;counter++){
                JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
                JSONObject second=new JSONObject();
                obj.put("ClassName", "sample.com");
                obj.put("Query", "query");
                obj.put("Message", "Successfylly");

                second.put("Number"+sequence++, obj);
                company.add(second);
                //file.write(obj.toJSONString());
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                json = gson.toJson(company);
                 file.write(json);
                file.close();

                }
```

Please guide me how to create new file if existing file gets fulled while writing json object into a text file.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell, as your code is not formatted well, but it looks like every iteration of your loop is overwriting the variable `json`.  Only the value of `json` at the last iteration of the loop will be written to the file.

Move the call to `file.write(json)` inside the loop.

Comment: Its just sample i posted here. My actual code is different but somewhat similar. But yes i am writing thousands of json objects into a text file. Could you please help me how to create new text file if existing file gets fulled.